# No me funciona el binding de Query Builder en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, laravel-5

Tengo una consulta un poco compleja y la estoy realizando con `DB::raw`, no quiero ponerle los parametros dentro de la cadena del query para no hacerla vulnerable a SQL Injection y demás tecnicas que puedan explotar un punto debil de mi consulta, entonces leyendo encontre que esa misma función `raw` recibe como segundo parámetro un arreglo con `clave => valor` usado para reemplazar las ocurrencias en la consulta que presenten este formato `:clave`.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$criteria = $request->get('criteria');
$data = DB::select(
    DB::raw("SELECT DISTINCT id, obtain_prefix.prefix, ".
        "(CASE WHEN prefix = 'WO' THEN number WHEN prefix = 'PN' THEN part_number WHEN prefix like 'COND%' THEN description ".
        "ELSE NULL END) AS right_value FROM (SELECT DISTINCT work_orders.id, work_orders.number AS number, ".
        "inventory_master.part_number AS part_number, part_conditions.description AS description, ".
        "(CASE WHEN number like :criteria THEN 'WO' WHEN part_number like :criteria THEN 'PN'".
        "WHEN part_conditions.description like '' THEN 'CONDITION' ELSE NULL END) AS prefix ".
        "FROM work_orders LEFT JOIN work_order_quotes ON work_order_quotes.work_order_id = work_orders.id ".
        "LEFT JOIN work_order_parts ON work_order_parts.work_order_quote_id = work_order_quotes.id ".
        "JOIN inventory_master ON work_order_parts.inventory_master_id = inventory_master.id ".
        "LEFT JOIN part_conditions ON part_conditions.id = work_order_parts.condition_id WHERE ".
        "work_order_status_id IN ( 1, 2, 3 )) obtain_prefix where prefix IS NOT NULL", compact('criteria))
);
```

He intentado con:

```
DB::select(DB::raw("...query...", ['criteria' => $criteria]));

DB::select(DB::raw("...query...")->addBinding('criteria', $criteria));

DB::select(DB::raw("...query..."))->addBinding('criteria', $criteria);
```

La consulta si la saco de la sentencia del `DB::select` y la pongo en un gestor de base de datos corre perfectamente. Ahora cuando ejecuto este codigo en php me da error pk no encuentra `:criteria`, el arma la consulta pero no termina de reemplazar los valores del `binding`, que podrá ser????

En los dos ultimos ejemplos de lo que he ido probando me indica que no encuentra la función `addBinding`

Hice el código mucho mas simple para comprobar si era por la complejidad de la consulta y probe con esto:

```
DB::select(DB::raw('select * from work_orders where number like :number', ['number' => '2019%']));
```

Me lanza el siguiente error:
`Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031  (SQL: select * from work_orders where number like :number
)'`

Como decia anteriormente es como si nunca reemplazara el `:number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El binding se hace en el método select() y no en raw().

El método raw() solo acepta un parámetro y es la consulta:

```
DB::select(DB::raw('select * from work_orders where number like :number'), ['number' => '2019%']);
```

Ejemplo de la documentación:

```
$results = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
```

---

Código del método raw, por si te quedan dudas:

```
/**
 * Create a raw database expression.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression
 */
public function raw($value)
{
    return $this->connection->raw($value);
}
```

Comment: Despues de tanto buscar llegue a tu misma conclusión es en select donde debo usar el binding ahora el problema es que tengo 3 veces `:criteria` y al ponerle en el binding ['criteria' => $criteria] me dice que la cantidad de parametros es incorrecta, tendria que pasarle :criteria1 :criteria2 y :criteria3 o deberia usar ? y pasar un arreglo con los 3 elementos repetidos. De igual forma gracias!!!!

Comment: Esa limitante la da PHP, no Laravel, según la documentación de PHP: `Se debe incluir un único marcador de parámetro para cada valor que se desee pasar a la sentencia cuando se llame a PDOStatement::execute(). No se puede usar un marcador de parámetro con nombre con el mismo nombre más de una vez en una sentencia preparada, a menos que el modo de emulación esté activado.`, pero hay algunas formas de saltar esta regla, una búsqueda en Google ayudará.